# How to customize MediaPlayer CompletionListener?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer

Here is something I would like to achieve. It is like a customization of what *setOnCompletionListener* already does.

We can have code like this:

```
var audioPlayer:MediaPlayer
....
audioPlayer.setOnCompletionListener {
  ... something very useful ...
}
```

to do something when an audio has finished playing.

What I want is to be able to do something when an audio has reached a certain point.
For example when it is half way, or when it has reached 100 seconds.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I believe only thing you can do is keep track of current position and then when it reaches, do your stuff

Comment: OK. And how would you keep track of the position? Having a separate thread for that? Or do you have any idea?

Comment: yes separate thread will be better

Comment: OK, I get the idea I will try that. I am not yet sure how I should implement the details but we'll see. I am not used with multi-thread programming in Android.

Comment: you can try coroutines

Comment: Yes I tried something on my own following you comment and I can get something working. What do you call coroutines ?

Comment: they make threading easier. new library in android

Comment: I am now looking at coroutines. It seems interesting but when I try to experiment to use them, for now it does not work. I read this https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#an-explicit-job. I suppose I need to do some preparation with my gradle, but I am not sure.

Comment: Yes you need to add dependency in gradle for coroutines